# error: expected ‘)’ before ‘<’ token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to learn c++ following a book. I've wrote this class definition using std::initializer_list in order to initialize a vector with a list of elements. Vector.h file looks this way:

```
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(int s);
    ~Vector();
    Vector(std::initializer_list<double>);
    void push_back(double);
    double& operator[](int i);
    int size();
private:
    double* elem;
    int sz;
};
```

When I try to compile I have this error message in line 6 (initializer_list one):

```
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘<’ token
```

I've also added this code to implement Vector constructor. Vector.cpp looks this way

```
#include "Vector.h"
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

Vector::Vector(int s)
{
    if(s < 0)
    {
        throw length_error("Vector::operator[]");
    }
    elem = new double[s];
    sz = s;
}

Vector::~Vector()
{
     delete[] elem;
}

Vector::Vector(std::initializer_list<double> lst)
{
    elem = new double[lst.size()];
    sz = static_cast<int>(lst.size());

    copy(lst.begin(), lst.end(), elem);
}

double& Vector::operator[](int i)
{
    if(i<0 || i>=size())
    {
        throw out_of_range("Vector::operator[]");
    }
    return elem[i];
}

int Vector::size()
{
    return sz;
}
```

but compilation also fails with this message:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
```

I'm using Code::Blocks width GNU GCC compiler and no extra compiler flags activated. I've tried checking "Have g++ follow the comming C++0x ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++0x]" in Code::Blocks, but errors remain and three new ones raise.

Comment: You *do* include the correct header file for [`std::initilizer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)?

Comment: `lst.size()` then next line `lst.size`, which one is it?

Comment: post the complete code please, so we can reproduce.

Comment: Also add your compiler version and flags you pass in. Some compilers don't support `std::initializer_list` yet, or require flags to enable the support.

Comment: I've tried to add `#include <initializer_list>` but error remains. I'm using GNC GCC compiler with no extra compiler flags activated in Code::Blocks.

Comment: What version of GCC are you using? ([How to find out](http://superuser.com/questions/206157/checking-version-of-gcc-compiler-in-codeblocks)). Note, that [GCC supports initializer lists since version 4.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) and you should add `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` for this to work. Otherwise your current code compiles fine (but not linking due to missing `main` function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `#include <initializer_list>` also
`lst.size()` instead of `lst.size`
and `lst.end()` instead of `ls.end()`.
Remember to enable c++11 in compilation.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited code to use `lst.size()` and misspelling. I've also added `#include <initializer_list>`. Error remains =(

Comment: did you add -std=c++0x into your compilation flags to enable c++11 features ?

Comment: I've just checked an option that says "Have g++ follow the comming C++0x ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++0x]". Now I've the old 2 errors posted in opening post plus 3 new ones =/

Comment: `/media/proyectos/c/Test/Vector.h|6|error: expected ‘)’ before ‘<’ token`
`/media/proyectos/c/Test/Vector.cpp|22|error: el prototipo para ‘Vector::Vector(std::initializer_list<double>)’ no coincide con ningún otro en la clase ‘Vector’`
`/media/proyectos/c/Test/Vector.h|1|error: los candidatos son: constexpr Vector::Vector(Vector&&)`
`/media/proyectos/c/Test/Vector.h|1|error:                 constexpr Vector::Vector(const Vector&)`
`/media/proyectos/c/Test/Vector.cpp|7|error:                 Vector::Vector(int)`

Comment: I've closed and opened again Code::Blocks and it works now (o_O). Thank you very much for your help